# How to check, if the two dates falls inbetween another two dates in c# or Vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a search page, where the articles can be searched by date. The search criteria is only with month and year.
So whenever the month is selected and clicked "filter" 
I take the start day of that month as "dtStartDate" 
and end day of the month as "dtEndDate"

The Articles which has to searched also has 
Effective Start date as "EffStartDate"
and Effective End date as "EffEndDate"

So what should be the condition if, Both these "EffStartDate" and "EffEndDate" falls inside 
"dtStartDate" and "dtEndDate" ?

I gave a try with this, but the results are not correct,

```
If (EffStartDate >= dtStartDate & EffStartDate  <= dtEndDate) 

    //Do Something     

ElseIf (EffEndDate >= ddl_FromDate & EffEndDate <= dtEndDate.AddDays(1)) Then

    //Do Something

End If
```

Scenario :
    Lets assume that there are two articles which are going to be searched using different dates.

```
Article - 1
EffStartDate = 11/7/2012
EffEndDate = 31/8/2012

Article - 2
EffStartDate = 1/7/2012 
EffEndDate = 28/9/2012
```

Now, in my search page, when i search for the article between 1/07/2012 to 31/07/2012
    I should see both the articles as result, because both the effstardate and effenddate somewhere 
    falls in between the dates used for search.
    But now i see only Artilce - 1 as result. Why ?

Comment: 1) If you can use a "between" clause in a database "select" - do it.  2) Otherwise, if you *must* do it in C# code (vs. a SQL "select"), then use [Date.Subtract/TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx).

Comment: Could you elaborate why the result is not correct? What is the result you get and the result you expect? Are you using linq to entities?

Comment: @gideon Pls check the updated question with scenario. Thanks

Comment: In both cases, your effective end date is outside of the search range. Based on the text of your criteria, you would want to exclude both articles and not show anything. Are you sure you don't mean _either_ the start date _or_ the end date falls in the date range?

Comment: Also, I'm concerned that you are writing this in If blocks at all. This should either be part of your database query, or done via linq. Both will yield better performance and are better for code maintenance.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn, The Effective dates are from datatable and search dates are from dropdown. How can i used Linq to achieve the above result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear to me from your example that the text of your criteria is wrong. The text of your criteria state that you only want to show an article if both the effective start and end dates fall within the date range... if the ***entire** effective range* of the article fits *entirely within the search*. But your example indicates that you want to show the article if *any part* of the date range fits within the range of search. An edit to clarify that would be helpful, but for now I will move forward assuming that the example is the correct interpretation.

You also seem to be mixing language syntax from VB.Net and C# together. You can't just mix syntax like that. The strongest influence in your code snippet seems to be VB.Net, so I'll use that in my example.

In VB.Net, you could write a condition that matches the example for your search like this:

```vb
If       (EffStartDate >= dtStartDate AndAlso EffStartDate  < dtEndDate.AddDays(1)) _
  OrElse (EffEndDate >= dtStartDate AndAlso EffEndDate < dtEndDate.AddDays(1)) 
  OrElse (EffStartDate < dtEndDate.AddDays(1) AndAlso EffEndDate >= dtStartDate) Then
   '...
End If
```

I'm also concerned that you're writing this code in an `If` block at all. If these dates are in a database, then the database is *by far* the best place to filter your results. If the data is elsewhere, then a linq-to-objects query of some type will likely yield both better performance and be shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: for the above scenario...your logic works fine. It gives me both the Articles as result. But when i search the article between 1/08/2012 to 31/08/2012, it should also give me both the Articles as result !!! But now it is not...It shows only Article - 1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question well , but like this its simpler

```
 bool isStartEffDateInside=(EffStartDate >= dtStartDate && EffStartDate  <= dtEndDate);
 bool isEndEffDateInside=(EffEndDate >= ddl_FromDate && EffEndDate <= dtEndDate.AddDays(1));

if(isStartEffDateInside || isEndEffDateInside)
{
 // do something global
  if(isStartEffDateInside && isEndEffDateInside)
    {
        //Do something when the two Effs are inside the StartEnd
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Even after using ur logic, the results are not expected. Please check the scenario which i have added now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [DateTime.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx) method?

Answer (score 0):

C# version:

```
if ((EffStartDate >= dtStartDate && EffStartDate <= dtEndDate) ||
    (EffEndDate >=  dtStartDate && EffEndDate <= dtEndDate))
{
    // Good Article
}
else
{
    // Bad Article
}
```